# Error 404 when posting on rails with RestKit iOS 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ios, post, request, xcode4.2

I'm having a weird problem with Restkit+iOS 5 + Rails: when I attempt to do a post on the server like this:

```
NSArray *topicsList=[self.topicsTV.text componentsSeparatedByString:@","]; 
RKParams *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: self.questionTV.text,@"question[text]", 
                                                               self.descriptionTV.text,@"question[detail]",                       
                                                                topicsList,@"topics[]", nil
                    ];
[[RKClient sharedClient] post:@"/questions.json" params:params delegate:self];
```

The log will be like this:

```
2012-01-11 17:24:21.725 APP[29087:fb03] I restkit.network:RKRequest.m:562 Status Code: 401
2012-01-11 17:24:21.725 APP[29087:fb03] I restkit.network:RKRequest.m:563 Body: {"error":"You have to register or login."}
```

Note that before posting I was logged at 100% because I could get access to some private content and what happened is that if I refresh the private content (get sent to server) it gives me this error:

```
2012-01-11 17:35:51.337 APP[29087:fb03] D restkit.network.queue:RKRequestQueue.m:455 Request <RKObjectLoader: 0x811c360> failed loading in queue <RKRequestQueue: 0xc60ea10 name=(null) suspended=NO requestCount=0 loadingCount=0/5> with error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain error 1004.).(Now loading 0 of 5).
```

Did that operation log me out? How should I mantain the login session alive?

Comment: theese are my parameters for the post:
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"rEwYQT9tKGtqW4Tp4wtBZTN5zl+HPOK5k/ZpGs0nAJc=", "question"=>{"text"=>"Prova prova prova", "detail"=>""}, "suggested-query-input"=>"", "topics"=>["argomento", "nuovo"], "variables"=>"prova-prova-prova-1", "commit"=>"Salva", "a"=>"questions"}

Comment: Basically i figured that could be a csrf that i don't keep...any idea?

Comment: Now the question is do i have to modify somethig in my ios app or in the rails app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What may be happening is the rails app is can't verify the CSRF token when your app runs a POST request.  When you run the GET request, it doesn't need to check the token (because GET requests don't change anything).  That's why you can GET something with a username and password, but can't POST something.  This [blog post](http://blog.technopathllc.com/2011/09/rails-31-csrf-token-authenticity-for.html) has some more info.

What I found to help is I disabled the check for any JSON request.

```
# In your application_controller.rb
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :if => Proc.new { |c| 
  c.request.format == 'application/json' }
```

Of course, you could also do this:

```
# Or this in your application_controller.rb
def verified_request?
  if request.content_type == "application/json"
    true
  else
    super()
  end
end
```

Either of these allow JSON requests to ignore the token, and you can CRUD appropriately.  Just know what you're doing if you choose to ignore the check.

Also: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3041